# Laravel show File from local storage, problem with Web Route

Tags: php, laravel, routes, local-storage

I have trouble to figure out how show uploaded file in the View under auth user. I have two tables in same database `users` and `files`. From my VSTO addon sending data about User and store to `users` and save file to local storage and save `file_path` to table `files`.

Both tables has same column `id_message`

User can log in to dashboard view via credentials in table `users` -> my bloblem is how to show file from laravel local storage for auth user.

Laravel storage is linked to `app/myFiles` each new file is saved with unique name -> `id_message` which is stored in both tables (users,files). Full path is `app/myFiles/{id_message}/file`

Im sure that i need somehing with `web route`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){
Route::get('apiFiles/{id_message}', function ($idMessage){
    $idMessage = session()->get('file')->id_message;
    return Storage::get($idMessage . '/' . $filename);
    });
});
```

and in view

```
<a href ="{{ URL::asset('apiFiles/{id_message}/') }}">Download</a>
```

cant send from my VSTO datas and upload file together and use only one table.
Is possible to solve this ?